# Higher-order functions and short forms

Tags: function, macros, clojure

Why we can write

```
 (defn factory-foo [] (fn [] (println "foo")))
 (apply (factory-foo) [])
```

but not:

```
 (defn factory-bar [] #((println "bar")))
 (apply (factory-bar ) []) ;throws NPE
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#((println "bar))` is translated by the reader to `(fn [] ((println "bar")))` - note the extra parentheses. `(println "bar")` here prints `bar` and returns `nil`, and then `nil` itself is called as a function because of the outer parentheses. `nil` is `null` in fact, and an attempt to dereference it results to NPE.

To avoid this just drop extra pair of parentheses inside `#(..)`: `#(println "bar")`.

Comment: You're welcome. Just FYI [here](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters) you can find extensive documentation on Clojure reader macros in general and on `#(..)` form in particular.